# How can I increase or decrease a value for <input type="range" min="1" max="30" value="15" step="1"> in JavaScript? Span for Value in html is made

Tags: javascript, html

[Image of my Pass Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7Sh.png)

If I move the pointer to the right or left the Value "00" doesn't do anything. It doesn't increase and decrease.

Hope for some help.

I've tried it with

```
const updateSlider = () => {
  document.querySelector(".pass-length span").innerText = lengthSlider.value;
  generatePassword();
  updatePassIndicator();
}
updateSlider();
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show more code? I'm not able to get a full picture of what is going on without it. Showing the relevant HTML and the rest of the JavaScript for your function would be helpful.

Comment: [there can be a thousand reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you don't show a [minimum of code to reproduce your problem, then you won't get any answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The `updateSlider(..)` *function* is not attached to the range slider as an *eventListener* so the text never gets updated. Quick and dirty solution: `<input type="range" oninput="updateSlider()">`. This will probably need some fiddling or proper Javascript assignment, but should work...

Answer (score 0):

This should update the label. I dont have your code, so I cant fit it to your case but making it work for you should not be too hard.

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
const sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider-value");

slider.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  sliderValue.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
    <input type="range" min="1" max="30" default="15" step="1" id="slider">
    <p id="slider-value">Slider Value: 00</p>
```